# "Lifted her under her arms" or "lifted her from under her arms"?

Tags: grammar, phrase-choice

Which is the correct version and why? Example sentence:

> I immediately lifted her (from) under her arms and pillowed her head on my lap

Note: I found both versions on Google.

Comment: Why do you want to use "from"? It is best not to add unnecessary words, especially prepositions.

Answer (score 1):

The use of the preposition from sounds unnecessary in the sentence presented.   You can say:

I lifted her/picked her up under (her) arms.